# how to resolve cve CVE-2020-28052 json-schema for npm

Tags: npm, package.json, cve, npm-vulnerabilities

By performing a dependency check using owasp 7.0.4 on my project, which uses java for BE and JS for BFE, i got ceveral CVEs noted over 8. One is the json-schema package used by npm. This the packages configuration in the package.json:

dependency:

```
"json-schema": "^0.4.0"
"npm": "^7.13.0"
```

when calling the command npm ls json-schema to check json-schema use i got:

```
+-- json-schema@0.4.0
+-- lerna@4.0.0
| `-- @lerna/add@4.0.0
|   `-- pacote@11.3.5
|     `-- @npmcli/run-script@1.8.6
|       `-- node-gyp@7.1.2
|         `-- request@2.88.2
|           `-- http-signature@1.2.0
|             `-- jsprim@1.4.2
|               `-- json-schema@0.4.0 deduped
`-- npm@7.24.2
  `-- node-gyp@7.1.2
    `-- request@2.88.2
      `-- http-signature@1.2.0
        `-- jsprim@1.4.1
          `-- json-schema@0.2.3
```

I see that i need to somehow force npm use the latest json-schema version.
Can please anyone give me a hint, if this is the right way and how to achieve it?

Comment: Update to my question: there is also a cve about npm itself: npm:7.24.2: CVE-2021-43616(9.8). So maybe by solving this the json-schema cve disappears..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by updating npm to 8.6.0